# Two way of implementing singleton with thread safe lazy initialization

Tags: java, multithreading

Static method and variable:

```
public class Singleton{

    private static Singleton singleton = null;

    private Singleton(){
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
        if(singletion == null)
            singleton = new Singletion();
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Second after Java 1.5

```
public class Singleton{

    private static volatile Singleton singleton = null;

    private Singleton(){
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(singleton == null){
            synchronized(this){
                if(singleton == null){
                    singleton = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

So what's the pros and cons for these two thread safe code and when should we use which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both implementations are thread-safe and valid.

The former is shorter. It is more readable and maintainable.

The latter is faster, and it's also faster than most people think. Depending on the implementation of the Java VM, reading a *volatile* variable is as fast as reading a *non-volatile* variable on x86. That means the overhead occurs only during the initialaztion. But as soon as the *singleton* has been initialized, there is no overhead at all.

If performance is really an issue, you should use the latter. Otherwise use the former, because the need for readability and maintainability is often underestimated.

Answer (score 5):

The second is thread safe but the following is much simpler, and faster as it doesn't require a synchronized block.

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    // define fields and methods here.
}
```

to access

```
Singleton.INSTANCE.method();
```

Note: an enum can implement an interface if you need.

Comment: Even if you need an abstract base class, the idea of relying on the JVM's classloader to do the necessary locking is sound and works fine with normal classes too.

Comment: ... unless initialization of the singleton might throw an exception. In that case, it can be probamatic that only the first caller is told about the root cause, and all subsequent access to the singletons fails immediately without attempting initialization again.

Comment: @meriton if this really makes a difference to your application, you have a design issue IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to go about doing a thread-safe singleton is via the [initialisation on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom):

```
public class Foo {
    private Foo() {}
    private static class Holder {
        private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }
    public static Foo getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This works in Java versions that didn't properly support the `volatile` keyword. The neat thing about this pattern is that it uses implicit locking only on the first access of `getInstance`. After that, access is unsynchronized. This is due to a fun little quirk of memory management and static loading in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The second one 'double checked' singleton is faster because it don't need to acquire lock whenever you ask for instance (despite first calls). Anyway best way to control life cycles of your objects is using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are of lazy initialization of singleton i.e. you initialize the singleton at the moment you need.The second example is an example of [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) which is primarily aimed at **thread-safe**.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is not thread safe. It would be thread safe if `getInstance` was `synchronized`.

If you need thread safety, use the second one.

There is a much simpler third way though, which is slightly different (the `Singleton` gets created at a different time):

```
public class Singleton{

    private static final Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

    private Singleton(){
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make `singleton` volatile?

Comment: This is wrong, the first version is perfectly thread-safe since the method is synchronized - no need for volatile! And the proposed replacement doesn't do lazy initialization so misses the point.

Comment: @Voo that's an edit. The proposed replacement does do lazy initialization, but it's done if you access any static field or call any static method in Singleton, not only getInstance.

Comment: @meriton shouldn't be, but I didn't add `volatile`, that was an edit from someone else.

Comment: Didn't see that the question was edited, sorry. And yes it is lazily loaded for some degree of laziness, but less so than the other approaches - should be mentioned.

Comment: If the only static method on Singleton is getInstance, which it should be if Singleton is a singleton, then it takes an unusual situation to make a difference.